Lifetime watcher in vault-agent kubernetes rendering the secrets before password rotation
I am using below annotations in my kubernetes pod to attach sidecar to my pod:
 "vault.hashicorp.com/service": "${url},
          "vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-$user.txt": "{{ with secret \"$static_url\" }}{{ .Data.password }} {{end}}",
          "vault.hashicorp.com/namespace": "${namespace}",
          "vault.hashicorp.com/agent-pre-populate-only": "false",
          "vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject": "true",
          "vault.hashicorp.com/auth-config-role": $role,
          "vault.hashicorp.com/agent-copy-volume-mounts": ${dcName},
          "vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-status": "update",
          "vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-command-$user.txt": "${command}",
          "vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-$user.txt": "$static_url",
          "vault.hashicorp.com/auth-config-path": "/var/run/secrets/token/..data/vault-token",
          "vault.hashicorp.com/agent-limits-cpu": 50m,
          "vault.hashicorp.com/agent-requests-cpu": 50m

However, I am noticing that my logs show :
 [INFO] agent.auth.handler: lifetime watcher done channel triggered
 [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: authenticating
 [ERROR] agent.auth.jwt: error removing jwt file: error="remove /var/run/secrets/token/..data/vault-token: read-only file system"
 [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: authentication successful, sending token to sinks
 [INFO]  agent.auth.handler: starting renewal process
 [INFO]  agent.template.server: template server received new token
 [INFO]  agent.sink.file: token written: path=/home/vault/.vault-token
 [INFO]  agent: (runner) stopping
 [INFO]  agent: (runner) creating new runner (dry: false, once: false)
 [INFO]  agent: (runner) received finish
 [INFO]  agent: (runner) creating watcher
 [INFO]  agent: (runner) starting
  agent.auth.handler: renewed auth token
 [INFO]  agent: (runner) rendered "(dynamic)" "$rendererpath"
 [INFO]  agent: (runner) executing command "${command}" from "(dynamic)" => "${secret renderer path}" 

I want to understand why lifetime watcher is rendering the secret before actual lease expiry? How can I make sure that secrets are changed only when password is changed in vault as per the schedule?
